# Makefile: shell command execution

Tags: makefile, sh

I have the following simple statement that works without problems in the shell:

```
if [ -z "$(command -v brew)" ]; then
 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
fi
```

in short: if the program is not found, then install it.

The problem is that I can't convert this construction into a Makefile. So far I understand that the construction itself should look like this:

```
if [ -z "$(shell command -v brew)" ]; then \
    /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)" \
fi
```

But how to correctly convert `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` string I do not quite understand. Could you give some tips in this matter?

Comment: This is the kind of thing I would make as a prerequisite for whatever your Makefile is doing, rather than running it in the Makefile itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dollar signs need to be doubled so make doesn't interpret them. Also there needs to be a semicolon at the end of the `bash` command to separate it from `fi` since the backslash will eat the usual newline command separator.

```
some_target:
        if [ -z "$$(command -v brew)" ]; then \
          /bin/bash -c "$$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"; \
        fi
```

Comment: Thx! Is there a difference between the two commands: `$(shell command -v brew)` and `$$(command -v brew)` ?

Comment: The former asks make to invoke a shell command then substitutes the value before make sends the recipe to the shell to run.  The latter sends the command to the shell along with the rest of the recipe for it to run.  Although _usually_ they are equivalent the former is subtly different and is generally considered bad form in makefiles.  A good rule of thumb for preserving sanity is you should never use make's `$(shell ...)` or `$(eval ...)` functions in a recipe.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break it into a couple of items.

Firstly, check for brew:

```
BREW := $(shell command -v brew)
```

Then check if the variable is set. If it's not set, then run the installer:

```
ifeq ($(BREW),)
    $(shell bash -c "$$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)")
    BREW := $(shell command -v brew)
endif
```

It's doable in an entire single shell command, but this breaks it into a couple of shell pieces.

the use of `:=` means that the evaluation happens at the time the line is parsed, which is how you get to check and override the value.

In a small, self-contained makefile:

```
BREW := $(shell command -v brew)

ifeq ($(BREW),)
$(shell bash -c "$$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)")
BREW := $(shell command -v brew)
endif

all:
    echo $(BREW)
```